# Timer countdown sql, asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, countdown

i have table with the desgin:

==========

```
id  (int, key)
itemName (nvarchar max)
offerClosing (datetime)
```

at the offerclosing i'm enter the date and time of the end of the offer to the item... example, now we at 16/5/2011 15:20 and the sale will end at 16:20, i want that at some lable will be  timer countdown that will countdown one hour untill we get 16:20.

hope that's clearly and that possible.

Comment: So this question is not really about SQL (removed the tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the countdown is displaying in a web browser.  You'll want to write the countdown in javascript.  Basically, store the offerClosing in a javascript variable and then use setTimeout with an interval of 1000ms (1s) to update the display of time remaining.

Comment: ok, but i need to display the countdown for each item, and to make the option to control the timer at admin page...maybe i'll do that without sql, but how, can you explain me how? thanks !

Comment: i use listview if that can help. i can to add lable to the itemtemplate... but what is the code

Comment: In your listview, include the offerClosing field and another field that calculates the time remaining (offerClosing - GETDATE(), assuming SQL Server) when the query is run.  In the onload event of the page, initialize have something like `setInterval("updateTimeRemaining();",1000);` and create the updateTimeRemaining funtion in a script of the page - in this function, you update the calculated column with something like `offerClosing - new Date`.

Comment: i think that i will re-post the question because i know better now what to ask. thank you, anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I think when you load the page you should subtract the offerClosing time - Datetime.Now.   Then you need to use javascript to subtract every second.  This is similar to what Ebay does when an auction is nearing close.   As far as the actual javascript I dont know offhand but I think you could google that